# fatal error: tlpi_hdr.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux

i trying to write a small file copy program which is specified in a book and in that they have included the following header file

```
#include "tlpi_hdr.h"
```

But its giving error as no such file or dir .  I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and the gcc version is  4.7.2 . Is there any specific path where the header file is present that i should give?

Answer (score 4):

That's not a standard header file.  From a quick google search, I found [this link](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/lib/tlpi_hdr.h.html), which indicates that it's a header defined and used by the book you're using.  You'll need to add that to your program, either by downloading it from somewhere or by typing it in from the reference in the book.